# Regular Expression for parsing parts of a sentence

Tags: regex, pcre, splunk

I am trying to create a regex that will parse a portion of a sentence within a Windows Log event.

As an example, EventCode=7035 generates the following:

```
The Network Location Awareness (NLA) service was.....sent a start
The Network Connection service was....sent a stop
The HTTP service was....sent a start
The HTTP service was....sent a stop
etc...
```

What I would like to parse out is, just the information between "The" and "service" and also the works start or stop.

That way I can build a list of services there were started or stopped.

Thoughts on this?

Comment: I'm actually trying to use it with Splunk. So it would be, EventCode=7035 |dedup Message | regex.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used Splunk Interactive field extractor.

Use following regex in your search as

For Service type

```
| rex "(?i)^The\s(?P<ServiceType>[^ ]+)\sservice"
```

For Service Status

```
| rex "(?i)sent\sa\s(?P<ServiceStatus>[^ ]+)"
```

Use fields "ServiceType" and "ServiceStaus" for further result and charting.

\s is for space or can use actual space " ".

Answer (score 0):

An example in Python (the text from the question is in `s`):

```
re.findall("(The.*?service).*?(start|stop)",s)
```

gives:

```
[('The Network Location Awareness (NLA) service', 'start'),
 ('The Network Connection service', 'stop'),
 ('The HTTP service', 'start'), ('The HTTP service', 'stop')]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can extract data with this regex:

```
The (.*?) service .*? (start|stop)
```

The data are in capturing group 1 and 2.